# Camunda springboot project not deploying on Camunda-ee tomcat server

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, camunda

I was following for this guide https://camunda.github.io/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/docs/2.2.0/index.html . And create my own new springboot-camunda project. Project structure

[image]

And I want to deploy war file, that I've created before, to Camunda-ee local server. And I expect to see this in Camunda cockpit. But it is not there. I'll so appreciate for any useful information how to deploy the Camunda springboot webapp project to the Camunda server.
Here's my code

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableProcessApplication
public class SlognSpringBootProcessApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(SlognSpringBootProcessApplication.class);

        springApplication.run(args);
    }
}
```

File `processes.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<process-application
        xmlns="http://www.camunda.org/schema/1.0/ProcessApplication"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <process-archive>
        <process-engine>default</process-engine>
        <properties>
            <property name="isDeleteUponUndeploy">true</property>
            <property name="isScanForProcessDefinitions">true</property>
        </properties>
    </process-archive>

</process-application>
```

File `application.properties`

```
camunda.bpm.auto-deployment-enabled=true
```

File `pom.xml`

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>net.slogn.camunda.bpm.spring.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-social-integration</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
    
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>
    
        <properties>
            <camunda-spring-starter.version>2.2.0</camunda-spring-starter.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
    
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension.springboot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>${camunda-spring-starter.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    </project>
```

Comment: Any error in the logs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First one note: when using `@EnableProcessApplication`, auto-deployment is disabled, so you can ommit this setting: `camunda.bpm.auto-deployment-enabled=true`.

To the main issue: what you are trying to do is package a Spring boot application as war and deploy on application server.

Checkout https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter/tree/master/examples/example-war, I guess you forgot to extend the initializer:

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableProcessApplication
    public class SlognSpringBootProcessApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {...}
```

so the engine is created on war deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I know what your problem is.

You are trying to create war file and deploy it on shared Camunda engine.
So let me tell you, this is not a proper way to do. As Camunda starter jar is embedded inside Tomcat; and your generated war file would use Camunda engine you already providing using starter jar.

To solve this issue, you need to use mix version of spring boot and spring framework.
Use spring boot for your project but for Camunda engine use spring framework.
You need to use shared engine runtime that is context.
Here you can see the pom example and the class you must mention.
http://javaint4bytes.blogspot.com/2019/11/camunda-spring-boot-with-shared-engine.html